# NuGet packages not restore in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have `Asp.netCore` solution which was working fine on `Visual Studio 2015` and then i moved to `Visual Studio 2017`. Now the problem is that in `Visual Studio 2017` on every nuget packages there is yellow exclamation mark. Following are solution which i have tried so far.

I'm using `Visual Studio Version: 15.3.1`

- Run as 'Administrator' and restore package.
- `Clear All Nugget Cache(s)` from `Tools > options > NuGet Package  Manager >` and again restore Nuget.

[image: You can see yellow mark on every nuget package]

Note: I have searched and found following solution and tried but did not resolve my issue.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42350609/4154016)

Answer (score 17):

I found the answer on another thread here and credit should go to @AxelWass although he did not specifically focus it towards this, it absolutely fixes this issue.  The above answer did not.

---

I had the same issue and solve it by opening the project in a text editor and deleting the following section:

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
     <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
   <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
</Target>
```

Once this is removed, it will resolve this nightmare issue that VS2017 and PM seems to be unable to resolve.  I too have run into this multiple times - especially when I blend many projects in the same solutions directory.

Comment: Also, you may need to run as Administrator as well. But this works!

Comment: How strange is it, I'm working this for hours and and try many things. I'm glad I've found this solution

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in [Microsoft Installing and reinstalling packages with package restore Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore), you should `Update-Package -reinstall`:

> `Update-Package -reinstall -ProjectName <project>` command where
>  is the name of the affected project as it appears in
> Solution Explorer. Use **`Update-Package -reinstall`** by itself to restore
> all packages in the solution.

If you still have the error, try edit your project file, check if there is A path refrence error there, also check the project/solution nuget config file.

Comment: That did not work for me and i got the same error again.

Answer (score 2):

By default, new installation of visual studio did not configure package source to search packages online. That caused the problem.

I found the answer with a little bit more work from a stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360953/1503372.

That answer mentions to use "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" url to restore packages. When I opened the package manager console in visual studio 2017, I found it was searching for packages from my PC only (offline search).

I then added "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" url as a source for restoring packages and it worked.

Follow below steps to add a package source.

1. [Right click project > Manage nuget package and you will see "package source label".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKwNE.png)
2. [Add highlighted URL to package source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjsTF.png)
3. [Select "All" as package source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckeZ9.png)

Once you have configured your visual studio to search for packages online, your all packages will be restored.

Comment: Finally a soluction that worked for me! In a fresh VS2019 installation.

Comment: This worked for me i was having https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a wrong configuration in the `nuget.config`. I don't know why, in this file there are some exclusion for my current project.

You can see your global configuration running this command in `File Explorer`

`%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`